# Area51 — Is there prevention for serial Meh-voting?

Tags: discussion, area-51, serial-voting

We know there's [serial up-voting and down-voting prevention mechanism](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) in the trilogy sites, but does this also exist for "Not a good example" votes in Area51?

Comment: +1 for "serial Meh-voting".

Comment: You write _Don't 'meh' me , bro!_ in a comment under the post.

Comment: Personally, I like the term "NaGE Rage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, similar measures are taken for "Not a good example" / meh votes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope not, because it's something I really wanted to do. I suppose I should have done it already, given the likelihood that folks like you are gonna try to spoil all the fun, but... Meh.

Comment: Voting "meh" on this answer.